Short story where unintelligent people sent to Mars are really crashing on Earth
Cryogenically frozen man is de-thawed to find humans rocketing unintelligent people to Mars when in fact the rockets are merely crashing on Earth.

I think that regardless of what terminology or perspective the original author may have used or held, there is no need for us to be talking about some people being "intellectually subhuman" here. People's degree or kind of intelligence does not make them less than human, or to use the German term, untermenschen.

This sounds like the short story "The Marching Morons", by Cyril M. Kornbluth. The story originally appeared in Galaxy Science Fiction in April 1951.
The main character is a real estate agent and con man who was placed in medical suspended animation in 1988, and awoke to a future where most of the human race had devolved to low intelligence. The few high intelligence humans left were waiting for the low intelligence people to die off so they could inherit the earth, but the revived con man convinced them to create a lemmings-over-the-cliff instinct in the stupid people — after he demanded great powers for himself in exchange for his advice. The low intelligence humans were convinced that Venus was a paradise, and shipped off in rockets that were really suicide machines. The passengers all died at lift-off from excessive G-force.
Here is a link to the story's Wikipedia article.

Most definitely.  Dupe of:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/213704/48874 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/291089/48874 — likely also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/196266/48874
